# GetQueuedCompletionStatus initial WSARecv with 0 lpNumberOfBytesRecvd issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, thread-safety, io-completion-ports

I am reading about IOCP through this article

http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancediomethod5i.html

This first WSARecv function he used with 0 `lpNumberOfBytesRecvd` to initiate the completion ports

```
if (WSARecv(Accept, &(PerIoData->DataBuf), 1, &RecvBytes, &Flags, &(PerIoData->Overlapped), NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR)

            {

                        if (WSAGetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING)

                        {

                                    printf("WSARecv() failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

                                    return 1;

                        }

            }

            else

                        printf("WSARecv() is OK!\n");

}
```

Now on the worker threads function where the application receives the IO post

it checks parameter `lpNumberOfBytes` of `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` for 0 also and then it closes the connection if it is

```
// First check to see if an error has occurred on the socket and if so

                        // then close the socket and cleanup the SOCKET_INFORMATION structure

                        // associated with the socket

                        if (BytesTransferred == 0)
```

When i tried it the first IOCP message posted the function `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` it always returning 0 in `lpNumberOfBytes` parameter because first `WSARecv` call was called with `lpNumberOfBytesRecvd` set to zero

I have tried to implement this code and i am having troubles to get the code working unless i choose to not use NULL in this parameter
in the first call to `WSARecv` so that the `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` function returning value 0 in `lpNumberOfBytes`  can be used as in case of all data recieved.

MSDN says to use NULL

> lpNumberOfBytesRecvd [out]
>
> A pointer to the number, in bytes, of data received by this call if
>   the receive operation completes immediately.
>
> Use NULL for this parameter if the lpOverlapped parameter is not NULL
>   to avoid potentially erroneous results. This parameter can be NULL
>   only if the lpOverlapped parameter is not NULL.

The code is not working well if i call `WSARecv` again (inside worker threads function) and all data were recieved this causes the `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` function to return immediatly without waiting even if INFINITE used and the worker threads enter in endless loop. No errors ever returned by `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` function it just acts as if there is more data but there is none.

`WSARecv` needs to be initiated with what value at buf size?

also should i use non blocking socket? or just normal blocking sockets since i use separate thread to accept connections so i think its fine because it won't freeze my GUI.

Comment: I fixed this problem by not receiving NULL size in first WSARecv. Now how can i know that i have received all data? where should i look in OVERLAPPED InternalHigh or the bytes received by GetQueuedCompletionStatus should be zero when all data read? or by checking the Bytes received on each call to WSARecv? how to know that i have received all data?

Comment: **>> how can i know that i have received *all* data**

you didn't. Valid successful completion is receiving one byte. After that you are expected to issue another WSARecv()